# Express (nodejs) + NGINX: Application not running on port 3000

Tags: express, nginx, centos7

The problem is this. I'm trying to build a test app as per the instructions.
My app.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello world</title>
   </head>
   <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "html",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My project",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I run the app (nodemon app.js), it works on the server side. But when I write "server_ip:3000", the browser displays "A connection attempt failed".
When I ran a similar application on another server with Apache, everything worked correctly. Perhaps the problem is in nginx. But I don't know what to do. Please tell me how to make the application work.
If it matters, my OS is CentOS 7.
Sorry for my bad english.

UPD:
My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  \here is server ip\;
        root         /var/www/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            root /var/www/html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        root /var/www/html;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/html;
        }

        location ~ .php$ {          
        root /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }



    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /var/www/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post NGINX configuration file?

Comment: @lpizzinidev I added (to the end of the question).